# Mapping a Char* to two Integers

Tags: c, dictionary, hashmap

I am looking for the fastest way to map a string to two integers, and map those integers to the string.

This is the structure for each element:

- char* name
- uint32_t license_id
- uint32_t ss_id

Each field is unique, all fields are constants, and no elements will be added after compile-time. Because they are unique, I want to make the following search functions:

```
uint32_t get_license_from_name(char *name);
uint32_t get_ssid_from_name(char *name);
void get_name_from_license(uint32_t license, char *name);
void get_name_from_ssid(uint32_t ssid, char *name);
```

From searching, I know it is possible to create a separate hashmap for each pair of search terms. **Is this my best choice?** I was hoping I could take advantage of the fact that these values are always known, unlike other questions I found.

Is there an O(1) solution to this problem?

Comment: If you have a hashmap implementation that's high quality and ready to use, then sure, go for it. But if you're thinking about implementing your own, I wouldn't. Instead, I would just keep 3 sorted lists, and use a binary search. You need a pretty good hash map implementation (with a really good hash function) to beat an O(log n) search.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for the comment. A binary search sounds like a better (and easier) idea over finding a good hashmap implementation. I think I will give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

How about using only one set implemented by binary tree?

```
Key:
     {name, license, ssid}

Function Compare:

     name_compare(name1, name2) || license_compare(license1, license2) || ssid_compare(ssid1, ssid2)
```

This is an O(logN) search.

Comment: During runtime I will only have one of the three fields, then I will need to do a search to find the other two fields. I think I will need three separate lists as user3386109 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to give some detail on the values.  If the values were originally integers, which have been converted to a character array for transport, than the problem can be solved by casting it to an int. Otherwise, your best option is to use stdlib.h functions like atoi() and atoc().

Based on your example code it looks like you are trying to extract two values from the same char array.  If this is the case I would recommend using memcpy() like this.

```
/* Based on what you wrote above I am assuming name is 8 bytes  */
int firstValueSize = 4/* whatever size in bytes the first number should be */;
int secondValueSize = 4/* Same with this */;
int *firstValue = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
int *secondValue = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(firstValue, name, sizeof(firstValueSize));
memcpy(secondValue, name + firstValueSize, sizeof(secondValueSize));
```

This should work if they were originally integers.  Otherwise you will have to use the functions mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Each field is a completely separate value. Consider the example of a Personnel record: Name: John Smith, Liscense ID: 123091342, SSID: 123-456-7890. Each of these fields is always unique for it's respective category. Also, the goal of this question is to implement the functions listed above, so I can't use them right now!

Comment: If nothing changes at runtime than the the char string in your struct is static and can be defined as a fixed size. You can cast that struct to whatever you want but frankly I don’t know why you need to.

Comment: How would casting the struct be useful in searching for a specific value? Cast it to what? I have 3000 constant elements. At runtime I will receive a single field and I need a fast way to find the struct using only that field. It needs to be fast because a great many search requests may need to be made in sequence at runtime, and a simple O(n) search has obvious performance hits.